# Iterate array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Consider I have a number of arrays as follows:

```
string[,] op1 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op2 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op3 = new string[9, 9];
```

How do I iterate over such arrays like the following?

```
int i;
int j;
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    // Iterate all the above three arrays here
}
```

I want to dynamically iterate all arrays starting with `op` by just changing the index.

I'm using C#.

Comment: If they are local variables, you cannot do that. If they are fields you *can* do that but you shouldn't. What's wrong with an array of arrays? Or a list of them?

Comment: Make an array or list of the arrays you want to iterate. Then iterate through the container array (loop within a loop). It sucks, but then you get what you asked for...

Comment: i know....but any alternate way of doing that??

Comment: what's the context of your problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make an array on the fly and iterate:

```
string[,] op1 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op2 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op3 = new string[9, 9];

foreach (var item in new[] { op1, op2, op3 })
{
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get clever by writing a method using the `params` keyword which will automatically create an array of arrays for you.

To do that, you have to write an intermediary wrapper class for the arrays, because the `params` keyword can only be used with a single dimensional array.

I really only provide this code for the curious - you probably wouldn't really need to go to these lengths in real code. However, if you *did* find yourself often wanting to iterate over a set of two dimensional arrays, you can use this approach.

After writing the (reusable) helper classes your code to iterate the arrays would look like this:

```
string[,] op1 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op2 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op3 = new string[9, 9];

IterateArrays<string>(processArray, op1, op2, op3);
```

Where the `processArray()` method would be along these lines:

```
static void processArray(string[,] array, int index)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processing array with index " + index);
}
```

Here's the full compilable example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ArrayWrapper<T>
    {
        public T[,] Array;

        public static implicit operator ArrayWrapper<T>(T[,] array)
        {
            return new ArrayWrapper<T> {Array = array};
        }
    }

    sealed class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            string[,] op1 = new string[9, 9];
            string[,] op2 = new string[9, 9];
            string[,] op3 = new string[9, 9];

            IterateArrays<string>(processArray, op1, op2, op3);
        }

        static void processArray(string[,] array, int index)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing array with index " + index);
        }

        public static void IterateArrays<T>(Action<T[,], int> action, params ArrayWrapper<T>[] arrays)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; ++i)
                action(arrays[i].Array, i);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, this is just to show how you can approach it. It'd just use @thumbmunkeys suggestion in real code.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[,] op1 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op2 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op3 = new string[9, 9];

List<string[,]> l = new List<string[,]>();

l.add(op1);
l.add(op2);
l.add(op3);

foreach(string[,] op in l)
{
 // iterate over op here
}
```

Or, if you don't want the additional lines to add the arrays to the list, you can:

```
List<string[,]> ops = new List<string[,]>{
    new string[9, 9];
    new string[9, 9];
    new string[9, 9];
}

foreach(string[,] op in ops)
{
 // iterate over op here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `list<string[,]>` containing the `string[,]'s`

```
string[,] op1 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op2 = new string[9, 9];
string[,] op3 = new string[9, 9];

//Create List, containing `string[,]`
List<string[,]> opList = new List<string[,]>();
//Add String[,]'s to list
opList.Add(op1);
opList.Add(op2);
opList.Add(op3);

//Loop over list
foreach(var itm in opList)
{
    //approach string[,]'s here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Easier would be to add the arrays to a `List<T>` and iterate the list to iterate the arrays:

```
List<string[,]> arrays = new List<string[,]>
{
    new string[9, 9],
    new string[9, 9],
    new string[9, 9]
};

foreach(var array in arrays)
{
    // Do something with the array...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<9;i++)
    {                             
        // Iterate your string op1,op2,op3 for the desired result.    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer and it's not event correct too.

Comment: This makes no sense. He has arrays with different names, not a single array.